# Array Index And Retrieving Values Generating Logical Error

Tags: c#

I have 2 different classes

```
class TollGate
{
    public void Check(int []numbers, int Token)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int s = numbers[i];
            if ( Token > s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Got To Wait");
                return;//this works
            }
            else
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Hold On Printing a Pass\n\"Happy Trip\"");//this doesn't   
                 return;
            } 
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[5]  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int r = rnd.Next(numbers.Length);
        int Token = (numbers[r]);
        Tollgate T = New TollGate();  
        T.Check(numbers, Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Cool"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Hot");
        Console.WriteLine("Freezing");
    }
}
```

Can't i use two return statements. How to make it just stop, by giving the message only once but it just goes along with the loop displaying it as many times as the loop.

Comment: Are you putting 5 integers into an array that has room for only 2?

Comment: simply you can use `if( Token > numbers.Max()) Console.WriteLine("You Got To Wait");`

Comment: @Adam Liss Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the logic in your for is very hard to understan I tried to guess what you are trying to do

```
class Tollgate
{
    public void Check(int []numbers, int Token)
    {
        int i;

        //change this for to the actual logic that you need
        //for (int numbers[i] = 0; numbers[i] < numbers.Length; numbers[i]++)
        for (i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            int s = numbers[i];
            if ( Token > s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Got To Wait");
            }
            else
            {
                //handle else logic

                //if need to stop the loop when this condition is met, insert a "break;" (condition is Token <= s)
            }   

        }
    }
}
class That
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
         Random rnd ;
         int r ;
         int Token ;
         Tollgate T ;  

         rnd = new Random();
         r = rnd.Next(numbers.Length);
         Token = numbers[r];
         T = new TollGate();  
         T.Check(numbers, Token); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you want:

```
public void Check(int[] numbers, int Token) {
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
       if ( Token > numbers[i]) {
          Console.WriteLine("You Got To Wait");
          return;
       }
    }
}

public static void Main() {
    int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2};
    int[] tokens = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int r = rnd.Next(tokens.Length);
    int Token = (tokens[r]);
    Tollgate T = new TollGate();  
    T.Check(numbers, Token); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As King King mentioned, you can add a `return` statement to the loop to stop the function at that point. If you want to exit the loop but not exit the function, add a `continue` statement instead of `return`. This jumps out of the loop, and is useful in real code, even though your example code is simple enough not to need it.

```
   bool waiting = false;
   if ( Token > numbers[i]) {
      Console.WriteLine("You Got To Wait");
      waiting = true;
      break;
   }
   ... // add any additional logic here. can check if(waiting)
```